# Globally storing user defined data in React Native for use in any file

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, async-await

Say I have an opening screen where the user picks a "Theme" for simplicity sake. I save their choice to AsyncStorage.

```
async setTheme(theme) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
        .then(() => {
            // Navigate to next screen
        })
}
```

I want to access this in a stateless file for specifying default colors. I can't export anything inside of a promise chain (i.e. Colors const) like below:

```
const ThemeColors = {
    ThemeOne: {
        main: '#1F78B7',
        secondary: '#F07634'
    },
    ThemeTwo: {
        main: '#E11D2D',
        secondary: '#FEED67'
    }
}

AsyncStorage.getItem('theme').then((theme) => {
    export const Colors = ThemeColors[theme];
});
```

I also cannot access anything outside of the promise object, naturally do to Async:

```
const theme = AsyncStorage.getItem('theme').then((result) => {
    const Theme = result; // Returns undefined
    return result; // Returns the promise object instead of the value
});
```

Am I missing something simple? Is there a solution outside of AsyncStorage for globally storing a piece of user defined information and accessing it at any point without passing as props? I'm probably just not familiar enough with Async/Promises. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can of course export the promise. But that won't relieve you from having to await it and handle errors everywhere you are using it.

Comment: If I try to export the result of a promise I receive an error:

`SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

Comment: Not the result of the promise, try to export the promise itself! (`theme` in your code, not `Theme` or `result`)